# Scapy - why do I always need an eight bit alignment?

Tags: python, alignment, packet, scapy

I noticed the following. If I write the following two classes

```
from scapy.all import *

class Incorrect(Packet):
    fields_desc=[
        BitField(
            "X", 0, 1
        ),
        BitField(
            "Y", 0, 2
        ),
        BitField(
            "Z", 0, 3
        ),
    ]

class Correct(Packet):
    fields_desc=[
        BitField(
            "X", 0, 3
        ),
        BitField(
            "Y", 0, 3
        ),
        BitField(
            "Z", 0, 2
        ),
    ]
```

And instantiate them

```
i = Incorrect()
c = Correct()
```

calling the `show2()` method of the `Incorrect` packet fails and it gives me the following output

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lk/code/BACnetFuzzingProject/src/scapytest.py", line 32, in <module>
    i.show2()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 848, in show2
    self.__class__(str(self)).show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 268, in __str__
    return self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 330, in build
    p = self.do_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 323, in do_build
    p = self.post_build(pkt,pay)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 337, in post_build
    return pkt+pay
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

but it works with the `Correct` packet. I think it fails because the size of the `Incorrect` packet is not a multiple of eight, at least it will fail every time it is not. But what's so bad about that? Why does it need to?

Comment: Scapy use struct.pack() an struct.unpack() to build and dissect packets wich require alignment I think that is why